# How to check if BackgroundFetching is enabled on iOS?

Tags: background, ios7

I like to determine if the user turned off Background Fetching in the Preferences app. If he turned it off my app won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code to do it:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable) {

    NSLog(@"Background fetch is available for the app.");
}else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied)
{
    NSLog(@"Background fetch for this app or for the whole system is disabled.");
}else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted)
{
    NSLog(@"Background updates are unavailable and the user cannot enable them again. For example, this status can occur when parental controls are in effect for the current user.");
}
```